# How to change attribute of MIMEMultipart object?

Tags: python, email

```
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
msg=MIMEMultipart('mixed')
msg['To']='test'
msg['To']='test2'
print(msg)
```

produces

```
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="===============1302686855105723805=="
MIME-Version: 1.0
To: test
To: test2

--===============1302686855105723805==

--===============1302686855105723805==--
```

I would expect test2 to replace test, but it just adds to recipients list. I don't want that. I want to replace current recipient and reuse current mimemultipart variable/message as I need to send multiple emails with same parameters to different recipients and I don't want all of them in header. How do I change value of current 'To' attribute, or discard current 'To' attribute in object of MIMEMultipart type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `msg.replace_header()` to overwrite an existing header, e.g.

```
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
msg=MIMEMultipart('mixed')
msg['To']='test'
msg.replace_header('To', 'test2')
print(msg)
```

Output:

```
From nobody Tue Oct 21 09:51:52 2014
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="===============0295162158244343135=="
MIME-Version: 1.0
To: test2

--===============0295162158244343135==

--===============0295162158244343135==--
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `replace_header()` method. This method replace the first matching header found in the message with header order and case. If there is no matching header then you will get a `KeyError`

In your case simply use `msg.replace_header('To','test2')`